# destructor for LinkedListelement in c++

Tags: c++, destructor

If I have next class:

```
class LListelement{
private:
   int i;
   double j;
   A *LListelement;
public:
   A(int i, double j,A *next): i(i),j(j),next(next){}
}
```

*How should i implement the destructor for this class?*

Comment: As empty operation perhaps?

Comment: That depends on who owns `next`, or `LListelement`, or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather stack than linked list. Each element should store address of the previous one. If it doesn't, you can remove only the first element. (the latest added) Default destructor is sufficient in that case.

**EDIT**
Possibly better way to implement the list is adding class which represents whole class, not only one element. It can store additional informations like address of the first element. Take pattern from `stl` implementation.

Also consider implementing `doubly linked list` instead of `singly linked list`.